# Creating a view in SQL Server from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have select statement which returns income or outcome for each day in two currencies:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
            WHEN C.Name LIKE 'B%' AND T.Income = 0 THEN 0-T.Amount
            WHEN C.Name LIKE 'B%' AND T.Income = 1 THEN T.Amount
            ELSE 0
            END) AS AmountBYR
      ,SUM(CASE
            WHEN C.Name LIKE 'U%' AND T.Income = 0 THEN 0-T.Amount
            WHEN C.Name LIKE 'U%' AND T.Income = 1 THEN T.Amount
            ELSE 0
            END) AS AmountUSD
      ,CR.Date
FROM [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[Transactions] T
JOIN [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[Bills] B ON B.BillID=T.BillID
JOIN [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[Currencies] C ON C.CurrencyID=B.CurrencyID
RIGHT JOIN [FinanceLabkovich].[dbo].[CurrencyRates] CR ON CR.Date=T.Date
GROUP BY CR.Date
ORDER BY CR.Date
```

[image]

I need to create view which show how much money the person has in total for each day

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [SYNTAX CREATE VIEW SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878954/syntax-create-view-sql-server)

Comment: @MikeD. this one looks like a running totals question.

Comment: I need to create view which count total money for each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 and later, you can calculate current balance using a running sum:

```
sum(column_name) over (order by date) as running_sum
```

To find only running sums at the end of the day, you could use a subquery:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  customer_id
        ,       sum(amount) over (
                    partition by customer_id
                    order by [date]) as balance
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by customer_id, cast([date] as date)
                    order by [date] desc) as rn
        from    Transactions
        ) as SubQueryAlias
 where  rn = 1 -- Only latest row per customer per day
```